# When trying to submit answer, Stack Overflow says my post has improperly formatted code

Tags: bug

I don't know why this is happening. It took me lots of minutes to make that answer, but I can't seem to post it. It's a code snippet, and I've put in indention already. Is this because of the <!-- language: lang-html --> stuff? And if that's the reason, how do you edit a code snippet?

The formatted code appears correctly.

Comment: Ah! I keep on forgetting that blank line! Didn't notice that.